# Can't disable SendMail in the gitblit server

Tags: gitblit

I am using GitBlit v1.2.1. For one of my projects  the `sendmail` post-receive scripts is enabled somehow which I can't delete. It is not present in the `Available` or `Selected` box. It's under the post-receive scripts label with a tag called `inherited`.

How do I disable the `sendmail` for this project?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your situation *sendmail* is inherited.  Have you checked `gitblit.properties` for globally defined hooks?

Comment: Could please let me know what I have to check in the gitblit.properties? I cant find anything like "hook" in the gitblit.properties file. Please help.

Comment: `groovy.preReceiveScripts` and `groovy.postReceiveScripts`